# Can I use a laptop backlight inverter as a tube power supply?

Tags: power-supply, inverter, high-voltage, vacuum-tube, ccfl

I would like to build a circuit that has a magic eye in it. That needs ~290V. I was wondering if I can/should use a CCFL inverter (salvaged from an old laptop) to generate that voltage, maybe driving it with an LM2576 so that it doesn't produce the usual ~600V. Are there any advantages or disadvantages of this method, if it is at all possible?

Comment: As you say, CCFLs work at 600+ V. If you are really lucky, the driver current limit will be in reasonable range and manages to work with the output clamped to 290 V. I would suspect most won’t. How much current does your magic eye require?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: The EM84 tube (magic eye) draws max 100mA @ 290V. I was thinking, I could "PWM" that 600V to get the 290V.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The chances are low.

CCFL inverters provide around 800 V AC sine wave, so you would need a HV rectifier with fast, low capacitance diodes and end up with an even higher DC voltage.

Most inverter circuits include some current measurement to verify the correct function of the backlight or they act as regulated AC current source. The inverter just stops if the current is inconsistent. It is very difficult to stay in the accepted current range with such a tube as load.

It is not possible to feed such a CCFL module with PWM, except some very simple unregulated modules containing just two transistors as active components.

I don't think you need 100 mA to drive an EM 84, the anode would become really hot at 29 W, but I will test this.